# How to use a DateTime formatted GridViewColumn of WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a small WPF application; all column templates are ok and they are textboxes but I couldn't find how to bind a DateTime Column (i.e. like a DateTimePicker) to GridViewColumn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work but you can check out [this](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/wpf-datepicker/). Also there exists some wpf controls in [here](http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonControlsLib).